# Populate Map from Json URL with AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, json, dictionary, android-asynctask

I tried to populate a GoogleMap by markers across latitudes and longitudes from a json parser ... I tried with AsyncTask but it does not work .. here is my code and thanks for your help:I hope that I'll can Populate Map from Json URL with AsyncTask

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        magasinsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received 
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mapActivity.this);

            pDialog.setMessage("Loading");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Markets: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    magasins = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MARKETS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < magasins.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = magasins.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String nom = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String ville = c.getString(TAG_VILLE);
                        String latitude = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
                        String longitude = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, nom);
                        map.put(TAG_VILLE, ville);
                        map.put(TAG_LATITUDE, latitude);
                        map.put(TAG_LONGITUDE, longitude);
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        magasinsList.add(map);


                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                //  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        //  NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                //  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                //  startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            double latg=Double.parseDouble(TAG_LATITUDE);
            double longg=Double.parseDouble(TAG_LONGITUDE);
            final LatLng local = new LatLng(latg,longg);
            Marker locations = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(local)
            .title(TAG_NAME)
            .snippet(TAG_VILLE)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.gps)));
//CameraUpdate center=
// CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5);

//googleMap.moveCamera(center);
googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);
            }
```

Edit :This is what the logcat displayed

```
 06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at com.example.mercure_fidelity.mapActivity$LoadAllProducts$1.run(mapActivity.java:180)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4170)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at com.example.mercure_fidelity.mapActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPostExecute(mapActivity.java:177)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at com.example.mercure_fidelity.mapActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPostExecute(mapActivity.java:1)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-08 00:07:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-08 00:07:51.669: D/dalvikvm(5396): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 7% free 13036K/13895K, paused 2ms+3ms
```

Edit II :Now the application dosen't ceash but it show me only my location and not the markers of other locations...I chaged the code in the postExecute method like that ...but the application crash again when I tried to access to the map.
this is the code (where results is a list of magasin: `results.addAll((Collection<? extends magasin>) map);` )

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (results!=null && results.size() > 0)
                            {

                                for(int i=0; i<magasinsList.size(); i++)
                                {


                                magasin g=results.get(i);
                                double latg=Double.parseDouble(g.latitude);
                                double longg=Double.parseDouble(g.longitude);
                                final LatLng local = new LatLng(latg,longg);
                                Marker locations = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(local)
                                .title(g.nom)
                                .snippet(g.ville)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.gps)));
    //  CameraUpdate center=
           //   CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latg,longg));
          CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5);

        //  googleMap.moveCamera(center);
          googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? Errors?

Comment: well ;the application crash when I try to access to the map I have those errors Error converting result... error parsing data org.json.jsonexception...  An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Comment: Post your logcat so we can see where they are and which one is the culprit

Comment: ok I'll add it in the question

Comment: At line 134 ? it's a comment  128 // Storing each json item in variable
       129 String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
       130 String nom = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
       131 String ville = c.getString(TAG_VILLE);
       132 String latitude = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
       133 String longitude = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);
       134 // creating new HashMap
       135 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

       136 // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
       137 map.put(TAG_PID, id);

Comment: I'm sorry I dont put the right logcat I'll edit it.

Comment: I have just correct what my locat contains for this class.

Comment: I saw that, thank you. Your error is at line 180...something is `null`. What is at that line?

Comment: That what I have at this line  Marker locations = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(local)
                .title(TAG_NAME)
                .snippet(TAG_VILLE)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.gps)));

Comment: `googleMap` is `null`. Where do you initialize it? You are welcome

Comment: I didn't inizialize it ,I just declared it as a global variable GoogleMap googleMap;

Comment: That's the problem. I have posted an answer that may help you.

Comment: If you have a lot of markers, you can also use `AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate()` to add them by batch to your map while your `AsyncTask` is still running.

Comment: Yeh that's right it dosen't crash now...but it still not showing me markers of places which latitudes and longitudes should be recuperated from a Json URL :/

Comment: I think my problem is in the postExecute method...I change the code like that in this method but my application crash when I tried to access to the map

Comment: I add something in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any variable that you use needs to be initialized to have a value. Otherwise, calling a method on that variable such as

```
googleMap.addMarker(...)
```

here results in a `NPE`. I assume it is a `GoogleMap` object with the name so you need to initialize it with the `getMap()` method.

You can find more information about this [here in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html) along with a sample and more help [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html)

I hope this helps